# Найти все элементы в списке после определенного

Tags: python

Есть список:

```
spisok = ['вася','петя','кирилл','анна','дима']
```

Мне нужно чтобы переменная `var elmnt` была равна всем элементам из списка `spisok` после определенного индекса.
То есть если взять индекс 2 (это будет `кирилл`), то мне нужно чтобы переменная `elmt` была равна `анна дима`. Количество элементов может изменяться, но мне нужно чтобы были известны все значения элементов после определенного индекса.

Comment: `spisok[index + 1:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def Fun1(spisok, word):
    i = 0
    for x in spisok:
        if x == word:
            return i
        i += 1
    return 0
def Fun2(spisok, word):
    string = ""
    i = Fun1(spisok, word) + 1
    for x in range(i, len(spisok)):
        string += " " + spisok[i]
    return string
```

Вызовите `Fun2(spisok, word)`, передав массив и слово.

```
s = Fun2(['вася','петя','кирилл','анна','дима'], "кирилл")
print(s)
```

Вывод:

```
анна дима
```